# Error on updating nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, nested-form-for

Three models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :sale
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :greenhouse
  has_many :orders
end
```

First a product is created. Then, an order can be made with one Product. Then, what I expect to be is, the Sale is filled with many Orders. But, when saving the Sale, it only ignores the Orders attached.

I've only found examples when the Sale creates the Order, or the parent object creates the Child object, but in this case, the child object, or the Order is already created, and only needs to be assigned or related with the new Sale.

How can I relate the child object with a new parent?

Comment: can you show the code where you have error?

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure that you have permit params at your `SalesController` something like this:

```
params.require(:sale).permit(:each, :sale, :field, :as, :symbol, :and, orders_attributes: [:each, :order, :field, :as, :symbol])
```

This is the most common issue which gives the described behavior. If not, we need some more information.